# Console within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I want a scrollable console within a JFrame, so people can see messages while using the GUI.

I'm currently using a JLabel, but this obviously only allows one message at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the [JTextArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) Swing component?

This tutorial should help you as there is a scrollable text area in one of the samples: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [JEditorPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), it is the most flexible.

Comment: Right, if the user has to edit the text. Else a JTextArea is simpler to use. I think it really depends on what the OP precisely needs.

Comment: JEditorPane is more flexible for future use. If the OP decides they want to add styles to the output etc, then it is much easier to do with JEditorPane, and its default use is just as easy as JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you JTextArea or JScrollPane.